# Can i specify the encoding before sending sms in j2me?

Tags: java-me, sms, sms-gateway

When I send a sms using my application to a sms gateway there is a problem of encoding. For example when the content of the SMS is  TUMA 1234567 the gateway receive something like ???5?...
I think that it is a problem of encoding.
I want to know if it is possible to send the sms in a specific encoding? if yes How?
Or you can give me another solution to resolve the problem.

Comment: Please provide some code to be able to see which library you are using.

Answer (score 0):

The Protocol Data Unit (PDU) contains an encoding field. You don't specify the library you use so it is difficult to provide more specific suggestions.

Comment: Where can I specify PDU for sending my sms